# android.media.AudioRecord - Invalid audio buffer size

Tags: java, android, audio

I am working on Audiorecorder to send and receive audio over UDP. I am getting the following error `Invalid audio buffer size`. I have even added a class to check the possible combinations of sampling rates.

```
public class audioCall {

private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;

public audioCall throws Exception {

    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

          AudioRecord audioRecorder = new AudioRecord (
                                          MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,SAMPLE_RATE,
                                          AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                          AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                          getValidSampleRates());
    }
}.start();

//check for the valid sample rates

public int getValidSampleRates() {
    for (int rate : new int[] {5644800, 2822400, 352800, 192000, 176400, 96000,
            88200, 50400, 50000, 48000,47250, 44100, 44056, 37800, 32000, 22050, 16000, 11025,8000}) { 
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        if (bufferSize > 0) {
            // buffer size is valid, Sample rate supported
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

here is my Log cat error report:

```
 I/audioCall: Send thread started. Thread id: 1669
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
 Process: com.example.app, PID: 25134
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid audio buffer size.
     at android.media.AudioRecord.audioBuffSizeCheck(AudioRecord.java:725)
     at android.media.AudioRecord.<init>(AudioRecord.java:374)
     at android.media.AudioRecord.<init>(AudioRecord.java:278)
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: What `bufferSize` do you actually pass to AudioRecord? `0` is not a valid option. -- P.s.: You should rename your question to reflect the actual error.

Comment: I just aprroved your edit. I tried in the beginning with `16000` but I ran into errors, stating that some of the devices are not supported for all sampling rates. So I included the above mentioned method

Comment: My buffer size is `byte[] buf = new byte[1024]`

Comment: `getValidSampleRates()` always returns `0` (unless you didn`t post the complete code) ?

Comment: `return 0`(automatic) has been inorder to return a int values

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your last comment. The class (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) has a constructor with 5 parameters (you have one that only uses 4?) -- the last param (`bufferSizeInBytes`) must not be 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196813/discussion-between-cantona-7-and-second).